# Assign static local ip address to OS inside virtual machine with bridged connection

Tags: windows-7, debian, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have win 7 OS on my laptop, and linux(debian 7) inside vmware. I have set the debian to have bridged connection with the network. I am connected by wifi, and if the wifi modem is being restarted the local ip address of the debian changes, e.g. from `192.168.0.106` to `192.168.0.102`. Is there a way to set the local ip address, so it will always remain the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `/etc/network/interfaces` like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/668310/configure-network-linux-on-vmware-nat-or-bridged)

and after that remember to restart your service using

`sudo service networking restart`

Comment: thanks man, just found the answer, I posted 15 seconds later :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the solution

here is the source
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-ubuntu-linux-convert-dhcp-network-configuration-to-static-ip-configuration.html

basically for debian

```
1) vim /etc/network/interfaces
2) comment/delete this line iface eth0 inet dhcp
3) add this
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.106  # this is the ip address you want to assign  
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
```